# Connecting to a ssh server based on interface up

Tags: bash, debian, alias

I'm trying to make a bash alias that connects via ssh to a server based on the availability of an interface. If the first interface is available, then connect through a specific IP, otherwise connect to another specific IP.

Here's what I came up with:

```
alias server='if [ ip a | grep -Eq ': tun0:.*state UP' || up == up ] then ssh root@10.10.10.10 else ssh root@192.168.1.130'
```

I put this line in .bashrc, but I always get the following error when opening a new terminal:

```
bash: alias: tun0:.*state: not found
bash: alias: `UP || up ': invalid alias name
```

and the alias itself doesn't work as when I try to use it I get the following output

```
>
```

**Just to clarify the question: I would like to ssh into a server using a certain ip address (192.168.1.130) if it's available, otherwise use 10.10.10.10. Also viceversa would be fine as it doesn't matter for me.**

Comment: So what is the problem, if you already have an alias?

Comment: And what happens? You should be getting an error message there. Did you try it? Also up will always equal up, what is that supposed to do? Did you mean to use a variable?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: The single quote before your regex ends the alias single quote. I suggest writing a executable script and making this the alias command.

Comment: just for curiosity, what is ` || up == up ` part supposed to do ?

Comment: It came out of trial and error...

Answer (score 2):

To check whether the `tun0` interface is up using `ip`, and pick one IP address depending on the result of the test:

```bsh
if ip address show tun0 | grep -q -F 'state UP'; then
    remote=10.10.10.10
else
    remote=192.168.1.130
fi

ssh root@"$remote"
```

Note that the `[ ... ]` isn't needed here.  Instead, we let the `if` statement use the exit status of the `grep -q` command.  The options used with `grep` ensures that there is no output and that the given pattern is used as a string rather than a regular expression.

The `ip` command is used in a way that gives only the information about the single interface we're interested in.

If you want to use this as an alias, I'd propose a shell function instead.  This makes it easier to get the quoting right, which is one of the issues in your suggested code.  It also makes it easier to get the syntax correct as we may use multiple lines with proper indentation to make the code readable.

```bsh
server () {
    local remote

    if ip address show tun0 | grep -q -F 'state UP'; then
        remote=10.10.10.10
    else
        remote=192.168.1.130
    fi
    
    ssh root@"$remote"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated suggestion. Any chance to test this without logging in and out every time?

Comment: @giovi321 You mean if you want to test modifications to the shell function? You could just copy and paste it into a terminal.  Then save the finished variant of the function in your `.bashrc` file or wherever you usually save aliases and it will be available in all new interactive shell sessions (e.g. in a fresh terminal) after that. No need to log out.

Comment: Makes sense... still doesn't work because both 192.168.1.130 and 10.10.10.10 are available but it connects to 192.168.1.130

Comment: @giovi321 Can't say much about that. What my code does is to set the `remote` variable to `10.10.10.10` if the `tun0` interface on the host is in state `UP`, and to `192.168.1.130` if it's not.  It then connects to the chosen address. That's all.

Comment: And if they're both UP?

Comment: @giovi321 It should be clear from the code that if `tun0` is `UP`, then it picks the `10.10.10.10` address, just like what I assumed your code was attempting to do.  The `tun0` interface is the only interface that is examined.  I'm not testing IP addresses, only the single `tun0` interface.

Comment: The problem is this is the output of ip address show tun 0:

4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.10.2 peer 10.10.10.3/32 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1ebc:a5d0:478:1018/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: @giovi321 Well, was I supposed to know that? Your code clearly tests for the string `state UP`, so I thought this was a given.  Now you say you want perform some other test?  What is it you want to detect to use the `10.*` address?

Comment: @giovi321 If you want to clarify your question, then consider updating the text. Stuff in comments will not be seen by most people and I will not update my answer to be out of sync with the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a single quote in your alias definition line. Try with defining the alias' command in double quotes.
On top, the trailing `fi` is missing, plus the semicolon before `then`.
One more note: the `ip a ...` is a "command substitution" and needs to be enclosed in `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the interface state from `/sys/class/net/$interface/operstate` file:

```
if [[ $(</sys/class/net/tun0/operstate) == up ]]
then
    ip=10.10.10.10
else
    ip=192.168.1.130
fi
```

Comment: It always gives "unknown" regardless of the interface or of the state of the interface. 
EDIT: actually it simply doesn't find the file if it's not connected

Comment: @giovi321 Only `up` to know if the interface is already UP. `down` , or `unknown` mean: your interface is down or it is not ready.

Answer (score 0):

Also while there are some good suggestions like evacuate functionality outside of the alias:

- you can do much more:

  - move into function - you can then alias it but it will work only in given shell

    - this one is most suggested here
  - move into separate script in `/usr/local/bin` and replace `ssh` invocation with `exec ssh`

    - this will make interepreter running the script replace itself with `ssh` which is what you want
    - you can alias that too

      - but it will also work from other shells and tools as well as standalone scripts

Finally, if you have a luxury of modern system and have access to `jq`, then instead of spelunking with `/sys` you can use new `-j` JSON output feature of `ip` to get any interface property you are interested in unmangled, without duct taping with `grep`:

```
# always gets first ip address assigned exactly
: ip -j addr show my-tun0 | jq -rj '.[0]|.addr_info[0]|.local' 
192.168.0.110%
```

Use `ip -j addr show my-tun0 | jq '.'` to gather all the properties available to you.

This is how you can reliably get same interface operating state that ip sees:

```
ip -j addr show wire0 | jq -rj '.[0]|.operstate' 
UP%
ip -j addr show wireless0 | jq -rj '.[0]|.operstate' 
DOWN%
```

Keep in mind that trailing "%" is artifact of my zsh used to indicate there is no newline at the end. Resulting string will work in shell expressions just fine.

Answer (score -1):

If im not wrong your conditional syntax need some work

`if [ condition ]; then <>;else <>? fi`

What do you want to achive by doing `up == up` ?

I came up with alias like this to connect when `tun0` is UP

`alias server="if [ $(ip a | grep -Eq ': tun0:.*state UP')  ]; then ssh root@10.10.10.10; else ssh root@192.168.1.130;fi"`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... but especially this part does not return "UP" $(ip a | grep -Eq ': tun0:.*state UP')

Comment: @pkalemba this (`$( )`) inside `[ ...]` test silent output of ` grep -q `  not return code.